# What high level languages are easily interfaced with C / C++?

Tags: c++, c, programming-languages

I have experience with OCaml. You had to write a stub for every function you wanted to use to convert the types even C int <-> OCaml int.
Linking was painful a well.
I don't even want to thing about mapping C++ objects.

What about other popular languages? Is it always a pain?

**EDIT:**

Please avoid duplicates. And state C and C++ interfacing capabilities separately.

**EDIT 2:**

Please be specific. "X can call C" doesn't give too much information.

Comment: It's not a high level language but ASM interfaces really nice with C and C++ ! :-). The other advice I can give you is that when you have too much trouble linking C/C++ Code with your Python code you can always make a nice DLL of your C/C++ code. Some people like COM dlls as well.

Comment: C++ **is** high language, event it is not **easy** one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nearly all of the scripting languages (Perl, Python, Lua, PHP, Ruby, Tcl) are intended to be embedded into C and C++.

A good survey paper of the relative merits of the APIs:

```
H. Muhammad and R. Ierusalimschy. C APIs in extension
and extensible languages. Journal of Universal Computer
Science, 13(6):839–853, 2007.
```

See also this [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281073/embeddable-language-with-good-string-manipulation-support) (and [my answer in particular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281073/embeddable-language-with-good-string-manipulation-support/1281650#1281650) ;)).

Comment: I love the syntax highlighting :)

Comment: Skilldrick: Me too. I wonder why it does that: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14664/how-does-so-syntax-highlight-citations-so-well

Comment: -1 : "designed to be embedded into C and C++." is false (as in, it's not the truth) for all the cited languages but Lua. Only Lua was designed for this, the other are adaptations made possible. There is quite a difference in the process of embedding a language that is designed to be embedded and embedding a language that it was not the primary design objective.

Comment: Klaim: I agree. I didn't intend to say that it was the original intention of all those languages. For many, it became an explicit goal later in life. However, it is a goal for all those languages to be embedded into C. Added better wording I think.

Comment: Sorry Klaim, Tcl was also designed from the start to be embeddable in C - see http://www.tcl.tk/about/history.html .

Answer (score 16):

Python has a very good C API. It can be integrated to C++ also very easily and conveniently using the boost::python C++ binding for the Python C API.

Comment: You should refer to the ctypes module and http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html

Answer (score 8):

There are varying degrees of enjoyment available among mainstream languages and their C interfaces. Gladly, you can use [SWIG](http://www.swig.org) for most of them.

Answer (score 5):

This problem has been important for over 20 years.  The state of the art in solving it is to define an *Interface Definition Language* or IDL.  You then have a tool that automatically generates those functions you used to write by hand. 
The other term in common use is *foreign-function interface* or FFI.

Unfortunately, most of them aren't very good.  From personal experience:

- tolua and SWIG aren't worth using for Lua and C; it's easier to write the binding functions by hand.  The IDL for tolua in particular is almost but not quite a C header file, so you wind up maintaining two versions of every declaration.
- tolua++ may be worth using for binding Lua and C++—the nuisance value of simulating C++ objects by hand is considerable.
- SWIG covers a lot of languages, but I have always found it difficult to use.

From reading about other people's experience:

- The [Glasgow Haskell Compiler](http://www.haskell.org/ghc) seems to have the nicest foreign-function interface, and if I recall correctly, the IDL is gratifyingly simple: you just give the Haskell type of the C function you're trying to import.
- [Standard ML of New Jersey](http://www.smlnj.org/) also seems to have a pretty nice foreign-function interface; there was a paper in BABEL-01 about it.

For any given language you want to interoperate with C, you should **ask about the foreign-function interface** and **ask if there is an IDL** and associated tools.

Comment: SWIG can be a pain, but it has the benefit of just having to learn it once.

Answer (score 3):

Python has a great C interface using built-in ctypes module.
In order to interface C++ modules, SWIG can be used.

Answer (score 3):

Python is a powerful and easy to learn high level language and has good documentation of extending it with C and C++:

http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html

Using this approach is simple, but you'd write your extensions explicitly for Python. Using SWIG (see [Extending Python with C++](http://wiki.laptop.org/go/Extending_Python_with_C++) for a nice little tutorial), you create the C/ C++ code as if it was to be run by itself plus an interface file that SWIG takes to create some wrapping code for you that you can use in Python (or other languages, for that matter).

Comment: Isn't Boost.Python considered more the thing these days?

Comment: pybind11 makes creating python binding a breeze these days. its a rewrite of boost::python.

Answer (score 3):

You might like this [recent comp.compilers thread](http://compilers.iecc.com/comparch/article/09-07-074) about various foreign-function interfaces. It was suggested that Haskell had one of the nicest.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use Python in this case, even if there is Boost.Python to help embedd it. Even Python people say it makes more sense to embedd C in Python than the other way around, simply because Python is not designed to be embedded.

I like to use languages that are specifically made to be embedded in C++ or C, like **Lua**, **Falcon** or **ChaiScript**. However I also like to have a full language available. If I want to write an application under heavy constraints (like games on consoles) I prefer to use **Lua** that is designed for this. Otherwise, I prefer to use **Falcon** or **ChaiScript**.

**Falcon** is a good alternative to Python in this case (embedding a high level language in C++) : http://falconpl.org
It's designed to work with C++ and even the standard libraries are implemented in C++.

I also like to use **ChaiScript** when I want to just include the headers and go with a scripring language : http://chaiscript.org
It's designed to be header only and easily integrated in C++ code. In fact it's made to work with C++ only.

Both are high-level language. Falcon looks more like Python and Ruby but have the advantage to propose far more programming paradigms than those two. Chaiscript looks like a simplified C++ so it might not be the best choice for people not used to such syntax but otherwise it's easily bound to your real C++ code. Falcon too, but not in the same way and the syntaxe is easier on non-programmers.

Answer (score 2):

Java has a nice native interface with JNI, C# has something very similar.

Comment: JNI is far to be nice... try JNA

Comment: Oh, apologies if JNI isn't the 'in' thing anymore; It's been 8 years since I last did Java :P

Comment: @lukasz in what sense? In JNI (and probably JNA) and C# you just write the header of the function as 'extern ...' and then you call it appropriately. What else are you looking for?

Comment: @Lukasz: I think that @dfa is alluding to the fact that JNI is hard to use.  If you make a mistake using JNI you risk crashing the JVM.

Comment: Well I never used JNI.
The standard issues are:
 - basic parameter type compatybility
 - more complex types like structs
 - overloading
 - object passing
 - variable argument functions 
etc

Link at least would be usfull.

Comment: @Lukazs: For example, if your C / C++ is not thread-safe (e.g. it calls some non-thread-safe library function), then you must make sure that you only call it via JNI from one Java thread.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but when using JNI, aren't there issues with endian-ness?  That is, Java uses big endian while the most common platforms (and therefore, C on the most common platforms) use little endian.

Answer (score 2):

[D](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/index.html) is [designed](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/interfaceToC.html) to be easily intefaced to C.

D 2.0 does have a [limited interface](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/cpp_interface.html) to C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

[R](http://www.r-project.org) is extensible via C, C++ and Fortran, this is described in the [R Extensions Manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html) and the contributed [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) package makes it easier to call C++ functions.

Answer (score 0):

Interfacing with C++ objects will always be painful, as there's no standard ABI (Binary interface).

Comment: Well. I guess you are talking about virtual functions. 
You can do a lot without them.

Comment: As long as the interface you use deals with calling conventions, layout, etc, rather than forcing you, the programmer, to do so, it should be fine.

Comment: If you can interface with ELF you should be able to interface with C++ objects relatively easily.

Answer (score 0):

I linked FORTRAN libraries in once.  I'd tell you more, but it's time for my nap.

Answer (score 0):

Tcl can call C/C++ code

Answer (score 0):

Lua's integration abilities with C (and by extension C++) are absolutely first class. Its a wonderful little language, too. I don' think it gets nearly the love it deserves.

link: http://www.lua.org/

Answer (score 0):

Common Lisp implementations will often have a FFI that works really well with C.  The nice thing is that you don't have to write any C code to use C libraries; all you need to do is write the declaration of the C function is Lisp.

Factor has copied this FFI system from Lisp.